# Generate xml namespace with php dom

Tags: php, xml, dom, namespaces

I have some problem with XML, namespace and PHP DOM.

This is my output that I should get:

```
<cd:Document xmlns="http://www.zbs-giz.si/Schemas/2006/ZBSxml/2.2" xmlns:cd="http://www.crea.si/Schemas/2004/Document/ZBSxml/2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.crea.si/Schemas/2004/Document/ZBSxml/2.0/ZbsCreaDoc.xsd">
<cd:Data>
    <cd:DataFormat>
        <cd:MimeType>text/xml</cd:MimeType>
    </cd:DataFormat>
    <cd:Content>
        <cd:EmbeddedData>
```

and this is my PHP code

```
$root = $doc->appendChild($doc->createElementNS('http://www.zbs-giz.si/Schemas/2006/ZBSxml/2.2', 'cd:Document'));
$root->setAttributeNS('http://www.zbs-giz.si/Schemas/2006/ZBSxml/2.2', 'cd', 'http://www.crea.si/Schemas/2004/Document/ZBSxml/2.0');
$root->setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance', 'xsi:schemaLocation', 'http://www.crea.si/Schemas/2004/Document/ZBSxml/2.0/ZbsCreaDoc.xsd');
```

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->formatOutput = true;
//set root element to correct cd prefix _and_ namespace:
$root = $doc->appendChild(
        $doc->createElementNS(
        $cd = 'http://www.crea.si/Schemas/2004/Document/ZBSxml/2.0',
        'cd:Document'));
//this is the bit of obscure magic: it will set the default namespace
$doc->createAttributeNS(
        'http://www.zbs-giz.si/Schemas/2006/ZBSxml/2.2',
        'xmlns');
//now continue as normal
$root->setAttributeNS(
        'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance',
        'xsi:schemaLocation',
        'http://www.crea.si/Schemas/2004/Document/ZBSxml/2.0/ZbsCreaDoc.xsd');
$data = $root->appendChild($doc->createElementNS($cd,'cd:Data'));
$dataformat = $data->appendChild($doc->createElementNS($cd,'cd:DataFormat'));
$dataformat->appendChild($doc->createElementNS($cd,'cd:MimeType','text/xml'));
$content = $data->appendChild($doc->createElementNS($cd,'cd:Content'));
```